# Infinite useEffect loop when using Redux with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am refactoring some code and turning my class components into function components as a way of learning how to use Hooks and Effects. My code uses Redux for state management and axios for database requests with Thunk as middleware for handling asynchronicity. I'm having an issue in one component that does a get request to retrieve a list of customers on what used to be `componentDidMount`. No matter what I try, the `useEffect` function gets into an infinite loop and continues requesting the customer list.

The component in question, `CustomersTable`, gets a list of customers from the database and displays it in a table. The component is wrapped by a container component that uses Redux's connect to pass in the retrieved list of customers to the `CustomersTable` as a prop.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    loadCustomers(currentPage, itemsPerPage, sortProp, (ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc'), {});
  }, []);
```

> loadCustomers is a Redux action that uses axios to fetch the customer list. currentPage, itemsPerPage, sortProp and ascending are state variables that are initialized to specific values on 'component mount'

I would expect that because I use the empty array that this would run only once. Instead it runs continuously. I can't figure out why this is happening. My best guess is that when redux gets the list, it returns a new object for state and therefore the props change every time, which then triggers a re-render, which then fetches a new list. Am I using this wrong in that Redux isn't meant to be used with hooks like this?

I ended up getting this working by adding the following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!list.length) {
      loadCustomers(currentPage, itemsPerPage, sortProp, (ascending ? 'asc' : 'desc'), {});
    }
  }, []);
```

I'm not sure this is the behavior I truly want though. If the list of customers was truly 0, then the code would continue to fetch the list. If the list were truly empty, then I would want it to fetch only once and then stop. Edit: Turns out this definitely doesn't work. It works for the initial load, but breaks the code for any delete or edit.

OK, providing more context here. The container component that wraps the CustomersTable is:

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import loadCustomers from './actions/customersActions';
import { deleteCustomer } from './actions/customerActions';
import CustomersTable from './CustomersTableHooks';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    customers: state.customers,
    customer: state.customer
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadCustomers, deleteCustomer })(CustomersTable);
```

The action, loadCustomers is:

```js
export default function loadCustomers(page = 1, itemsPerPage = 50, sortProp = 'id', sortOrder = 'asc', search = {}) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loadCustomersBegin());
    return loadCustomersApi(page, itemsPerPage, sortProp, sortOrder, search)
      .then(data => dispatch(loadCustomersSuccess(data)))
      .catch(() => dispatch(loadCustomersFailure()));
  };
}
```

the reducer for customers is:

```js
export default function customersReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_CUSTOMERS_BEGIN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: true, list: [], totalItems: 0 });
    case types.LOAD_CUSTOMERS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: false, list: action.customers || [], totalItems: action.totalItems });
    case types.LOAD_CUSTOMERS_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: false, list: [], totalItems: 0 });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I unfortunately can't post much of the CustomersTable itself because things are named in a way that would tell you what company I'm working for.

Comment: The above code seems to be correct. Can you post the entire component of create a reproducible demo

Comment: This is code for work, so I unfortunately can't post the entire component, nor could I post a demo.

Comment: There is no need to post your code as it is, we just need a dummy setup similar to your which reproduces the issue

Comment: Hmmm, I would have to post a lot of the code to show a similar setup, including all of the Redux code. I guess I was trying to ask a more theoretical question. Since I am not loading the customer list into state, and instead loading it into Redux state then passing it in as a prop, am I causing the infinite loop because this registers as changing props and therefore a rerender?

Comment: you are right but that certain useEffect is passed with a second argument empty array which tells react that it should only run once, so possibly there are other code in work here causing the issue so we need to see more context.

Comment: ...say something in parent makes component to be re-created instead of being updated. so `useEffect` might actually run just once per component life cycle.

Answer (score 8):

So, if i understand your code correctly, you are dispatching the `loadCustomers` action in child component within `useEffect` but you read actual data in parents `mapStateToProps`.

That would, of course, create infinite loop as:

1. parent reads `customers` from store (or anything from the store, for that matter)
2. renders children
3. child fetches `customers` in `useEffect`
4. properties on parent change and cause re-render
5. whole story goes on forever

Moral of the story: don't `dispatch` from presentational components. or, in other words, `dispatch` an action from the same component you read those same properties from store.

Comment: I find it quite hard to mentally map out what's updating what, so this answer really helped me, and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

On every render you get new customer object because mapStateToProps if doing shallow equal. You could use memoized selectors to get customers, and it won't rerender when is not needed to.

```
import { createSelectorCreator, defaultMemoize } from 'reselect';

const createDeepEqualSelector = createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize, deepEqual);

const customerSelector = createDeepEqualSelector(
 [state => state.customerReducer.customers],
 customers => customers,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the most voted answer here.

> 4. properties on parent change and cause re-render
> 5. whole story goes on forever

A re-render will not call the function argument of `useEffect` when the 2nd argument of dependencies is and empty array. This function will only be called the 1st time, similar to the life cycle method `componentDidMount`. And it seems like this topic was created because that correctly expected behavior wasn't occurring.

It seems like what is happening is that the component is being unmounted and then mounted again. I had this issue and it brought me here. Unfortunately, without the component code we can only guess the actual cause. I thought it was related to `react-redux` `connect` but it turns out it wasn't. In my case the issue was that someone had a component definition within a component and the component was being re-defined / recreated on every render. This seems like a similar issue. I ended up wrapping that nested definition in `useCallback`.